# Why won't my YouTube Player API load videos whose ID has an underscore?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I've tried the `player.loadVideoById` and the `player.loadVideoByUrl` but whenever the YouTube video has an '_' in the ID the video will not play. All other videos work fine.

This is an example of an id that will not work: 'NJ6_A9tQvlE'.

Answer (score 0):

It has underscore and no misstakes:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I'm talking about when using the YouTube API for playing videos (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) not just using the embed code that YouTube gives you to share.